# receive user-authored messages with python-telegram-bot library

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)

app = ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN").build()



async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('Name')


    async def name_add(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
        name = update.message.text
        print("Name:" ,name)
        

        app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, start_last))

    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, name_add))

    
async def start_last(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('age')

    age = update.message.text
    print(age)




app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
app.run_polling()
```

Hello I want to pull the messages written by the user.
example bot:

user- /start

enter your bot-name

user- mike

bot- enetr your age

user- 18

bot - name: mike age:18

it will work like this, I get the name but it does not come out of the function. I can get the name but not the age because the name does not come out of the function I get

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.